# Xamarin.Android CrossPlatform Application not Run

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I have Installed Xamarin with Visual Studio. Xamarin Forms Application Run well on Ios and Windows Platform but it does not run on Android Phone.
I am getting Error

```
Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression StateError       

Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist. App4.Droid
```

Please Help me to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it is a packaging error do you have to install Xamarin.Android.Support.v7 this package to particulate project it it is not working then try next option like,

Download .jar file for particular API Level 23.0.1.3 and Extract it on C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.0.1.3\embedded\